# passing macro variable within AWK loop

Tags: bash, awk

AWK is not my forte (yet) and I have build a function where I can pass 2 macro variables (2nd macro variable is not used in the following reduced example) ; function looks like

```
twopq () {
 echo codee=$1 type=$2 
 echo RUNNING $1 $2
 cd ./DRP$2
 cat ../perfincodee$1.txt | awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1,1,$3,$4}' > ./temp1
 cat ../ERC/PEVani$1 | awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1,$4,$5}' > ./temp2
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next} ($1 in a) {print $0, a[$1]}' OFS=" " ./temp2 ./temp1 > ./infic.txt
 rm temp*
}
twopq 3 bpl
```

pb is that my code does not work in the awk line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next} ($1 in a) {print $0, a[$1]}' OFS=" " ./temp2 ./temp1 > ./infic.txt
```

There could be a confusion between $1 calling for the variable '3' and $1 calling for the 1st column in the merge of temp1 and temp2
any clue / tip would be appreciated
cheers

Comment: Rather than `cat a | awk ... > a1` then `cat b | awk ... > b1` then `awk a1 b1` maybe try without temporary files and useless-use-of-cat like this `awk '{print $0}' <(awk '{print $2}' a) <(awk '{print $3}' b)`

Comment: Explanation for above comment here https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection

Comment: Hi Mark - I really appreciate the better code you sent - did not quite worked yet but I'll work on that- many thanks!

Comment: What is a _MACRO_ variable?

Comment: sorry @user1934428 - bad SAS habit - what I call a macro variable in the bash sample would be $1 and $2 that can take different values - in the example $1=3 and $2=bpl - what is the proper name for those?

Comment: I think they are just called *"function parameters"*.

Comment: roger that for future posts - thanks mark!

Comment: In bash terms, they are called _positional parameters_, because they are passed from the calling program to a child process or a function. In awk, they denote fields and I would call them _field variables_ (awk does not provide positional parameters, but uses the `$n` syntax for accessing the fields of the line which is being processed). You can find the term _macro_ for instance, when you are using [`mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m4), or the C-preprocessor.

Comment: @user1934428 thank you for the info - all very informative !

Comment: You should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it will tell you about.

Comment: By the way `-v OFS=' '` in your first 2 awk scripts and `OFS=" "` in your third awk script all set OFS to a blank char so there's no reason for you to be doing it in 2 different ways in those scripts, but also a blank char is the default value of OFS anyway so setting it manually to a blank does absolutely nothing, you could just remove those statements where you're setting it.

Comment: You should ask a new question about how to do what you're trying to do in that function because calling awk 3 times and creating temp files is the wrong approach, you only need 1 call to awk and you don't need temp files.

Comment: @EdMorton great help! esp the shellcheck.net - really appreciate it. About your last point, I will need to free some time to optimise my code - for now I'm out of the hole and need to plod on :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass variables to `awk` like this:

```
awk -v var1="$1" -v var2="$2" ... '{...awk code...}' file(s)
```

Comment: Hi Ivan - thanks for the help - I did not think of using -v so great help! It also helped me noticing a bug in another part of my code while testing - my code can work without the -v - thanks a lot for the help!